nginx can't follow symlinks even after "disable_symlinks off;" setting
I have django/gunicorn/nginx based site. The static files when changed and deployed to the server get uploaded to /home/username/src/static folder. The website itself is provided from /home/username/src folder. Then I copy the static folder to /var/www folder and restart nginx. Everything works.
So to make things simpler and reduce the possibility of error, I decided to create a symlink in /var/www folder pointing to /home/usernam/src/static folder. I also added the "disable_symlinks off;" directive in nginx.conf file and restarted gunicorn and nginx. I am now getting "net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)" error.
What should I do?

Does the user that is running nginx have permissions to read files in your home directory?  By default, only your user has any access to your home directory.  You could set nginx to run as your user, or use the defaults and host your website from /var/www/ where you were able to get it working.

You are correct. The nginx didn't have permissions to /home/username directory.
